# Get part of string between specific symbols

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have got such kind of text

```
select * from Table1; select * from Table2;create table Table3...sdsd; sometext===[]sometext; aaaaaaaabbbbb;select * from Table5; sdsddasdsd;
```

and I need to get only part of string which starts 's' and ends ';' by using Regex; Thanks.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can depend on the programming language and regex library you are using.

```
(s.*?;)
```

Should work. This will produce 1 match for each SQL statement. If you can add your language to the question it may help in case you get a different output.

The main interesting bit here is the non-greedy operator ?, which stops it matching across the whole string and matches the shortest length possible.

http://regexpal.com/ is a good place to try regular expressions.

Comment: more efficient. `s[^;]*;`